# how to use tesseract to get polyline of a character?

Tags: tesseract, polyline

I am now using tesseract to recognize character. Now I find tesseract has the outline of each recognized character. My problem is can I convert the outline to a polyline? That is if i can not find the corresponding character, I can use polyline to draw like a char.

Answer (score 0):

Tesseract's ResultIterator class ([API examples](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/APIExample)) can produce the coordinates of the bounding boxes of the recognized characters; however, the boxes are rectangles, not contours of the character shape.